# Javascript - Multiple buttons have almost identical code but very different results

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a [Simon Game](https://cf.geekdo-images.com/opengraph/img/MvF-j0KKUDFYusKFW8gV-m6gh6w=/fit-in/1200x630/pic288369.jpg) using html, css, and js. For those unfamiliar with the game, basically the game lights up its buttons in a random order, and if the player is able to push the buttons in the same order, the sequence will repeat and increment by 1.
My code first generates the order in which the buttons will be pressed, and then starts lighting up buttons accordingly. The green and blue buttons work as they should: they light up and turn off in the order. But the red and yellow buttons aren't working properly. When it's their turn to light up, they just repeat the light up command and never move on to the setTimeout function that is meant to turn them off. I'll post what I think is the part of the code where something is going wrong, and a link to the project on codepen below that. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
//random is my array of numbers from 1-4, generated randomly, which
//determines the order of the buttons which the user must match.
//j is a counter that increments to iterate through that array.
if (random[j] == 1){
  $('#0').addClass('green-lit');
  $('#audio1')[0].play();
  litID.push(1);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#0').removeClass('green-lit');
  }, off);
}
else if (random[j] == 2) {
  //this console log and the following addClass command just repeat forever
  console.log('red on');
  $('#1').addClass('red-lit');
  //this audio never gets played
  $('audio2')[0].play();
  litID.push(2);

  //so I think I can safely presume that the code never reaches this 
  //setTimeout function
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#1').removeClass('red-lit');
    console.log('red off');
  }, off);
}
```

[Here is a link to the project on codepen.](https://codepen.io/kaydeejay/pen/WJGbwN?editors=0010)

Comment: Did you notice the `TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined` in the console? I’d suggest you fix that.

Comment: you should fix `$('audio2')[0].play();` to `$('#audio2')[0].play();`

Comment: Same thing for `audio3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot the `#` in your jQuery selector for `audio2`. This causes an error when trying to get index `[0]` on `undefined`, and stops javascript execution. Fix it like below:

```
if (random[j] == 1){
  $('#0').addClass('green-lit');
  $('#audio1')[0].play();
  litID.push(1);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#0').removeClass('green-lit');
  }, off);
}
else if (random[j] == 2) {
  //this console log and the following addClass command just repeat forever
  console.log('red on');
  $('#1').addClass('red-lit');
  //this audio never gets played
  $('#audio2')[0].play(); //fix this line!
  litID.push(2);

  //so I think I can safely presume that the code never reaches this 
  //setTimeout function
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#1').removeClass('red-lit');
    console.log('red off');
  }, off);
}
```